# Is connection pool shared based on connection string value?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi, connection-pooling

I have ASP.NET Core Web API. The app has three functionalities that connects to DB. `EF DbContext`, `Hangfire` and `Serilog Logging`. All 3 reads the connection string from appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer"],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=serverip;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;",
          "tableName": "Logs",
          "schemaName": "logging",
          "autoCreateSqlTable": false
        }
      }
    ]   
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=serverip;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

in Programs.cs I have configured Serilog that auto reads the connectionString from appsettings

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("http://*:30000")
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
       {
           if (!hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsLocal())
           {
               logging.ClearProviders();
           }

           Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
           .CreateLogger();
           logging.AddSerilog();
       });
```

in Startup.cs we have Hangfire and EF DbContext using the same connection value

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

        //dbContext
        var connection = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        
        services.AddHangfire(config => config.UseSqlServerStorage(connection));

}
```

Serilog, has separate entry in appsettings for connection string but the value for the connection string is same.
Each funcationality has its own SQL schema. DbContext -> dbo schema, Hangfire->hangfire schema, Serilog ->logging schema

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

> A connection pool is created for each unique connection string. When a
> pool is created, multiple connection objects are created and added to
> the pool so that the minimum pool size requirement is satisfied.
> Connections are added to the pool as needed, up to the maximum pool
> size specified (100 is the default).

Since the value of the connection string is same, does that mean all these 3 funcationalities sharing the same connection pool?

**UPDATE 1**
The reason I asked this question because we were seeing error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period
> elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
> occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
> was reached.

Here is my implementation of service. Since service is registered with `Scope` lifetime, the DI container should dispose service at the end of request and that should dispose the dbContext as well.

```
public interface IBaseService : IDisposable
{
}

public abstract class BaseService : IBaseService
{   
 
    private bool _disposed = false;

    protected readonly MyDBContext _dbContext;

    protected BaseService(MyDBContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }       



    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged and - optionally - managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing"><c>true</c> to release both managed and unmanaged resources; <c>false</c> to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
            // Free any other managed objects here.                    
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        _disposed = true;
    }       
}

public interface IOrderService : IBaseService
{        
    Task<Order> Create(Order order);     
}

public class OrderService:BaseService,IOrderService
{
   public OrderService():base(MyDBContext dbContext)
   {
   }

   public async Task<Order> Create(Order order)
   {
       _dbContext.Orders.Add(order);
       await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       
       // at this point I am guessing the SQL connection will be closed by the DBContext
   }
}


and in Startup.cs it service is regiered with Scope lifetime

services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
```

Comment: Only if they are in the same process. Even if so, it's probably fine. Connections released from the pool are meant to be short-lived and quickly returned (this is why should always wrap them in a `using` block). So _if you're following good practices_ the 100 connections is often more than enough for the vast majority of cases.

Comment: in .NET Core you typically inject DBContext in the service. So i cannot use using block for DBContext. However, my service implements `IDisposable` and that disposes DBContext. See my update1

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn can you please define Process in this context? All 3 will be executed on different threads. When we encountered SQL timeout error because of connection pool, the error did not get logged in the DB.   I think logger was unable to obtain SQL connection.

Comment: DBContext is an attribute of Entity Framework, not necessarily .Net Core. However, I'm not sure the scoped lifetime is doing what you expect here. I typically use raw ADO.Net, but my limited EF experience says you should be limiting your db context lifetimes similar to limiting your connections.